# Error in sample functional tests with Yii

Tags: php, selenium, yii, functional-testing

Recently I've discovered Yii framework and started learning it. I've generated app skeleton using **yiic** tool, installed PHPUnit, SeleniumRC and attempted to run functional tests provided by skeleton app (I didn't change anything).

```
> phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
```

Report said following:

```
There was 1 error:
1) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for testComplete().
ERROR: Element link=Logout not found.
```

I found that there was a 'Logout (demo)' link, not just 'Logout'. If I change php code in testcase, all tests pass ok. Is it error of Yii developers or am I missing something?

Comment: any chance we can see your test code for around that?

Comment: in protected/tests/functional/SiteTest.php, line 44: $this->clickAndWait('link=Logout');  should be $this->clickAndWait('link=Logout (demo)');

Comment: If you fixed it, you should make your comment an answer galymzhan. :)

Comment: Please [report it here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/list) so we'll not forget to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 1.1.6 fixes this bug.

```
if($this->isTextPresent('Logout'))
    $this->clickAndWait('link=Logout');
```